# Default_url in Paperclip Broke with Asset Pipeline Upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, asset-pipeline

I'm using Paperclip and have a default_url option like this for one of my attachments:

```
:default_url => '/images/missing_:style.png'
```

The asset pipeline obviously doesn't like this since the directories moved.  What's the best way to handle this?  I have two styles for this picture (:mini and :thumb).

Comment: does the accepted solution still work for you? As per [my comment below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646549/default-url-in-paperclip-broke-with-asset-pipeline-upgrade#comment37771994_9775710), I still haven't found a solution for this

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
:default_url => ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('missing_:style.png')
```

Then put the default images in *app/assets/images/*

Comment: this not works in production env, following error raised:


 attachments/:class/:attachment/:style/missing.jpg isn't precompiled
 actionpack (3.1.4) lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:147:in `digest_for'

Comment: @lidaobing and what do you do in production?

Comment: Sorry, I actually remember running into an issue when we pushed to production but now I don't remember what it was or what the resolution was. On my latest project, I just used ':default_url => "/assets/avatar_defaults/default_:style_avatar.png' and store the defaults under app/assets/images/avatar_defaults/.  That has been working fine in all cases.

Comment: @JofoCodin Rails, by default, doesn't compile assets when running in production (it's slow). You need to precompile assets before pushing to production: `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Comment: This solution does not work for me in Rails 4.1 in either my development or production (Heroku) environments. In both environments, my images are in `app/assets/images`, and when I open a Rails console and try `ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('missing.png')`, it prints out the properly fingerprinted path (`/assets/missing-longmd5hash.png`). However, the default URLs returned by `Model.attachment.url` for instances of Model without an attachment only return `/missing.png` (doesn't have the `/assets` prefix or the fingerprint at the end). Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Comment: How I solved the problem with production environments in Rails 3.2 was by passing `:digest => false` to `asset_path`. You see, it doesn't need to find the non-existent file called "missing_:style.png" if we don't require a digest.

Comment: If this solution doesn't work see my comment on github https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1597#issuecomment-123496278 . In short: just wrap #asset_path in lambda.

Comment: @icem Using his lambda method was the only working solution for me as well running S3 storage on Heroku deploy (Rails 4.2)

Answer (score 25):

*Tested only on Rails 4.*

To make it work in production, we have to pass the name of an existing file to the `asset_path` helper. Passing a string containing a placeholder like `"missing_:style.png"` therefore doesn't work. I used a custom interpolation as a workaround:

```
# config/initializers/paperclip.rb
Paperclip.interpolates(:placeholder) do |attachment, style|
  ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("missing_#{style}.png")
end
```

Note that you must **not** prefix the path with `images/` even if your image is located in `app/assets/images`. Then use it like:

```
# app/models/some_model.rb
has_attached_file(:thumbnail,
                  :default_url => ':placeholder',
                  :styles => { ... })
```

Now default urls with correct digest hashes are played out in production.

The `default_url` option also takes a lambda, but I could not find a way to determine the requested style since interpolations are only applied to the result of the lambda.

Comment: This works for me. What a nice and cool solution. How did you figure that out? I never knew they implement "interpolates" method

Comment: Thanks. You can find out a little bit more about Paperclip interpolations on this [wiki page](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Interpolations).

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a bit new in rails and I don't know how to use this approach. Where I have to put the interpolation code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @halbano: You can create a paperclip initializer (`config/initializers/paperclip.rb`) and simply paste the code in there.

Answer (score 15):

Just make sure that *in your views* all your paperclip images are rendered with `image_tag`.

```
<%= image_tag my_model.attachment.url(:icon) %>
```

That way, all of paperclip's `:crazy :symbol :interpolation` will have happened to the url string before Rails tries to resolve it to an asset in the pipeline.

Also, make sure your `:default_url` is asset compatible...if **missing_icon.png** is at **app/assets/images/missing_icon.png**, then `:default_url` should be simply `"missing_:style.png"`

```
<%= image_tag my_model.attachment.url(:icon) %>
# resolves to...
<%= image_tag "missing_icon.png" %>
# which in development resolves to...
<img src="/assets/missing_icon.png">
```

Comment: Essentially, all you need to do is ensure your `default_url` setting doesn't start with a slash. The default `default_url` is `/:attachment/:style/missing.png`, so just changing that to `:attachment/:style/missing.png` will cause everything to start working in production (with precompiled assets) and continue working in dev...

Answer (score 8):

I got the error(even for a single style) at assets:precompile with

```
:default_url => ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('missing.png')
```

So I hooked with a method like this

```
# supposing this is for avatar in User model

has_attached_file :avatar,
   :styles => {..},    
   :default_url => lambda { |avatar| avatar.instance.set_default_url}

def set_default_url
  ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('missing.png')
end
```

I didn't try for multiple styles, but this works for my situation.

Comment: Worked properly for rails 4.1

Comment: Or all in the lambda: `default_url: -> (a) { ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('missing.jpg') }`

Answer (score 3):

this works for me:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :small => "52x52",
:medium => "200x200>", :large=> "300x300", :thumb => "100x100>" },
                              :default_url => "missing_:style.png"
```

just place images in your assets/images folder named: missing_large.png, missing_medium.png, missing_small.png and missing_thumb.png

Comment: Thank you! no one else explained that the :style would just take it from the previous description!!!!

Answer (score 2):

In rails 4.0.0 and paperclip 4.1.1 this worked for me:

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
  styles: { medium: '300x300#', small: '100x100#', thumb: '25x25#' },
  default_url: ->(attachment) { 'avatar/:style.gif' },
  convert_options: { all: '-set colorspace sRGB -strip' }
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having to use something like the following.

```
DEFAULT_URL = "#{Rails.configuration.action_controller.asset_host}#{Rails.configuration.assets.prefix}/:attachment/:style/missing.png"
has_attached_file :art, :styles => { :large => "398x398#", :medium => "200x200#", :small=>"100x100#", :smaller=>"50x50#", :smallest=>"25x25"}, :path=>"images/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension", :default_url => DEFAULT_URL
```

I statically compile the assets and was getting an error in production, this helped me.

Answer (score 1):

In your model file, change this line:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
```

by removing this:

```
/images/
```

Create a folder for each style, in this example medium and thumb, in assests/images and place an image called missing.png there (or whatever name you want it to have of course, as long as it matches the file name in the model)

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by using a custom interpolator.

The problem from other solutions that suggest using

```
:default_url => ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('missing_:style.png')
```

is that you will get an error saying "missing_style.png" is not precompiled.

I created an initializer with the following code:

```
module Paperclip
  module AssetPipeline
    module Interpolator
      def self.interpolate(pattern, *args)
        ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path Paperclip::Interpolations.interpolate(pattern, *args)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then in my model I would do:

```
has_attached_file :image, interpolator: Paperclip::AssetPipeline::Interpolator, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `/` from `/images/pic.png`: `images/pic.png`