# Specifying default url for missing images in Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Using Rails 3.2 and Paperclip 3.4.2. I have the following:

```
# photo.rb
  has_attached_file :data,
    :styles => {
      :picture_lightbox => ["600x450>", :jpg], 
      :picture_preview => ["250x250^", :jpg], 
      :picture_thumb => ["76x76^", :jpg]
    },
    :default_url => "placeholder_:style.png"

# shop.rb
has_many :photos

# show.html.erb
<% if !shop.photos.blank? %>
  <%= image_tag(shop.photos[0].data.url(:picture_thumb)) %>
<% else %>
  <%= image_tag('placeholder_picture_thumb.png') %>
<% end %>
```

While this works, but it defeats the purpose of specifying `:default_url` in `photo.rb`, because I don't know a way to show the default image when `shop.photos` (which is an array of photo objects) is blank.

This is not about asset pipeline. It's about how can I detect that `shop.photos` is blank, then it returns the default image url, instead of explicitly specifying the default image url. What should I change?

Comment: Please, Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646549/default-url-in-paperclip-broke-with-asset-pipeline-upgrade

Comment: @BachanSmruty Thanks, but it's not about asset pipeline. It's about detecting `shop.photos.blank?`, then use the `default` image.

Comment: Bad, but working solution: to build new shop photo if shop.photos is blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `:default_url` on Paperclip in your case is to set a default url for `photo` object. But you have a problem with showing a default "cover photo" of `shop`. This is additional logic in your code. You cannot achieve this only with Paperclip's `:default_url` option. If you want to take advantage of `:default_url` option, I will suggest you to create a method in `shop.rb` which looks something like this:

```
def cover_url
  # I guess you want to use first photo based on your code
  photos.first_or_initialize.data.url(:picture_thumb)
end
```

Then in your view you will have just `<%= image_tag(shop.cover_url) %>`

Comment: I was thinking of this method too. Guess this is the way. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Actually the default URL will work when you have a relation like

```
class User
has_attached_file :photo
end
```

when user.photo is nil, default user.photo.url will return default URL.

What you have done in your case seems correct to me.