# How to set default image in paperclip ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

Recently I installed **Paperclip** gem and I am struggling to make the default image work on my system, I put the image file inside `assets/images/pic.png`.

This is code in my model `User`:

```
has_attached_file :pic,
  :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
  :default_url => 'missing_:avatar.png'
  #:default_url => 'assets/images/avatar.png'

has_attached_file :attach
```

This is code inside my `AddPicPaperClip` migration:

```
def self.up
  add_column :users, :pic_file_name,    :string
  add_column :users, :pic_content_type, :string
  add_column :users, :pic_file_size,    :integer
  add_column :users, :pic_updated_at,   :datetime
  add_attachment :users, :pic
end

def self.down
  remove_column :users, :pic_file_name
  remove_column :users, :pic_content_type
  remove_column :users, :pic_file_size
  remove_column :users, :pic_updated_at
  remove_attachment :users, :pic
end
```

In order to display the image in my show I have this code:

```
<%= image_tag @user.pic.url(:medium) %>
```

Could you help me find a solution, in order to show a default picture before a user inputs his own profile picture?

Comment: Might this be a dup of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646549/default-url-in-paperclip-broke-with-asset-pipeline-upgrade)?

Comment: Thank you very much, i fixed the problem thanks to your post.

Answer (score 11):

I got the error in ermenkoff's solution.

**Error**: AbsoluteAssetPathError

It was fixed by **removing** "/assets/"  from the url.

```
:default_url => ":style/missing_avatar.jpg"
```

Images are stored in:

```
app/assets/images/medium/missing_avatar.jpg
app/assets/images/thumbs/missing_avatar.jpg
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. I need to access my "whale.jpg" file in my assets/images directory. I am typically showing my profile picture as <%= image_tag (at)user.profile.avatar.url %> but how would that work for default? I tried <%= image_tag (at)user.profile.avatar.url, :default_url => "whale.jpg" %> with and without the :style tag, but it didn't work. NOTE: I had to use "at" because stack wouldn't let me post the symbol.

Comment: Hi @Jubl, Can you post the error message ? And make sure the images are in subfolders too according the sizes.

Comment: There is a small error: the folder needs to be called /thumb/ (or "thumbnail", or whatever name you gave your style), NOT /thumbs/. Automatic pluralisation doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 2):

```
:default_url => "/assets/:style/missing_avatar.jpg"
```

:style is substituted with medium or thumb, depending on what you've requested. You should put your defalut images in:

```
app/assets/images/medium/missing_avatar.jpg
app/assets/images/thumbs/missing_avatar.jpg
```

Comment: There is a small error: the folder needs to be called /thumb/ (or "thumbnail", or whatever name you gave your style), NOT /thumbs/. Automatic pluralisation doesn't apply here.