# Default images not showing up with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

my default image is broken when it tries to load.

my code:

```
has_attached_file :background, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "default-logo.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :background, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

Rendered:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://test.dev/default-logo.png
```

`default-logo.png` is located in my `assets/images` folder.  Why is it now showing up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Default\_url in Paperclip Broke with Asset Pipeline Upgrade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646549/default-url-in-paperclip-broke-with-asset-pipeline-upgrade)

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly set the path in the `has_attached_file` line of code to tell Paperclip *exactly* where to look for your default image.  What I have used in the past is `ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path`, passing in the asset file name.

So, for your code, try:

```
has_attached_file :background, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("default-logo.png")
```